# How to identify a contact by pressing it in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to delete a certain contact, but not by finding its ID or name or etc..., just by pressing it and asking if I'm sure I want to do it.

I've made some questions about this topic but the real way I want it to determine the one contact I want to delete is by pressing it.

This is the class I used, which I updated for it to work in my Activity:

```
private void deleteContacts() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
            contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null);
        }
    }
```

Apparently this removes all contacts (I think?).

**How do I make it so instead of deleting ALL contacts, it only deletes one that I want to.**

Process of how I want it work:

1. Pressing this button:

[image: Remove Contact]

2. The contacts or maybe just the button change color, so the user knows when is the delete feature on (I'll try doing this myself)
3. Clicking on a contact
4. A "Are you sure you want to remove this contact?" box appears (Not important right now)
5. After being sure of it, the contact is removed

I hope I was precisive enough for people to understand my question.

Comment: Your question is too broad, if your question is "why does this code deletes all contacts?" the answer would be that you have a while loop that iterates over all contacts and deletes them one by one. you need to pass into this function a `loopupKey` or a `contact ID` to identify the specific contact in question so the function can know which contact to delete

Comment: Alright, is there a way to add a `contactID` to all existent contacts and added ones? That way I can actually make work of the contactID's unique variability.

Comment: of course there is, but it's a part of your code which reads the list of contacts... and it's very specific to your UI