# How to delete a specific contact by pressing it, in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-contacts

So I made this question but nobody answered: [How to identify a contact by pressing it in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70339068/how-to-identify-a-contact-by-pressing-it-in-android-studio)

Maybe because it was hard to understand, so I'll explain in a short manner.

How can I remove a specific contact by pressing it?

I saw this similar question, but I don't know what to insert in the `deleteContact(Context ctx, String phone, String name)` parameters.

Anyways, here's the code used there:

```
public static boolean deleteContact(Context ctx, String phone, String name) {
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
    Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                    ctx.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                    return true;
                }

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't know if this is the best code to use in my case, but here's the button connected to the "Remove Contacts" button code in the MainActivity.java:

```
Button rem_btn = findViewById(R.id.rem_btn);

rem_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> deleteContacts());
```

As you can see, `deleteContacts()` needs parameters, I just don't know what context is needed (apparently none in the MainActivity, but then half the code disappears; I didn't even know my phone had a String attached to it; I also don't know if the name stands for the contact's name or the phone's name).

If you want more details, the link is at the top.

Really hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i use that code same in my application is work totally fine in all devices the parameters are

```
deleteContact(MainActivity.this, name eg-jhony, number eg-123578996)
```

But make sure to also add this in your mainactivity for working the parameters

```
public static boolean deleteContact(Context ctx, String name, String phone) {
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
    Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                    ctx.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                    return true;
                }

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I made this question a while ago, and I decided to make an entirely new display that removes contacts, which isn't working very well either. I would need to implement this in my new class if that's the case, except the one I see here receives specific data, while mine, one I saw in a video, is suppose to remove once I tick the box next to it. It works in the video, just not in mine.